# Adding custom View to layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, view, programmatically-created

I'm using this library: https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

I need to add the component "it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView" to my layout programmatically.

I've tried this but nothing is visible...

```
View w;
    w=new it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView(MainActivityDynamic.this);
    w.setMinimumHeight(500);
    w.setMinimumWidth(500);
    w.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    linear1.addView(w, 0);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What your getting...what is your problem? any exception?

Comment: Try this    w.setVisibility(true);

Comment: @Chandrakanth no exceptions, my problem is that I want to create that custom view, but when I add it to the root view, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Define your HListView in a XML file, than inflate it in your code and add it programmatically using addView.